# Rails 3.2 <tr> tags and <td> tags being stripped when rendering partial

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, html, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a nested form where I display a few fields for a has_many relationship.  When I render a partial which contains the fields my tr and td tags are being removed.  the div tag is not however.  What can I do to make sure the tags aren't being stripped?

_form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for @invoice do |f>
.
.
.
<table>
  <th>Qty</th>
  <th>Description</th>
  <th>Price</th>
  <th>EA/C</th>
  <th>Amount</th>

  <%= f.fields_for :invoice_line_items do |builder| %>
    <%= render 'invoice_line_item_fields', :f => builder %>
  <% end %>
</table>

<% end %>
```

The table tag when viewed in the browser source code only contains the headers and closes before the nested form partial is rendered.  The partial completely strips all of the tr and td elements.

_invoice_line_item_fields

```
<div>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <%= f.text_field :qty %>
    </td>
    <td>
      <%= f.text_field :description %>
    </td>
    <td>
      <%= f.text_field :price %>
    </td>
    <td>
      <%= f.text_field :ea_c %>
    </td>
    <td>
      <%= text_field_tag :amount %>
    </td>
    <td>
      <%= f.hidden_field :_destroy %>
      <%= link_to "remove", "#", :class => "remove_line_items" %>
    </td>
  </tr>
</div>
```

Comment: your table is invalid. `<th>`'s are not in a `<tr>`

Comment: Also remove the `div` surrounding the `tr`s in the partial - that too is invalid, and quite possibly causing your problem.

Comment: How do you know that the tags are stripped? Do you use something like an inspector? These tools show the parsed document tree, not the actual source code.

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out in the comments your markup is incorrect and what the browser shows you might be highly modified due to it trying to guess what you actually meant.

A correct structure for a table would be:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <th>Header1</th>
    <th>Header1</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>You can have divs here ...</td>
      <td>You can have divs here ...</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Don't mix in other HTML elements except inside your `<td>...</td>`-tags and you should be fine...